# Thread Safe Servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets, thread-safety

I am working on a JSP MVC web application. I am confused about Thread-Safe Servlet concept. Following is my code, please tell me is it thread safe or not. Also, tell me the reason that why it is thread-safe or not thread-safe.

JSP Code;

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Personal Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="PersonalData" method="post" action="PersonalDataServlet">
        First Name:<input type="input" name="FirstNameField"><br>
        Last Name:<input type="input" name="LastNameField"><br>
        Email:<input type="input" name="EmailField">Without @ part<br>
        <input type="Submit" value="Submit Data">
    </form>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <%
        out.print(request.getAttribute("FullName") + "\n");
        out.print(request.getAttribute("EmailAddress"));
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet Code;

```
package Servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import Model.WelcomeName;

@WebServlet("/PersonalDataServlet")
public class PersonalDataServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String FirstNameServlet;
        String LastNameServlet;
        String EmailServlet;

        FirstNameServlet = request.getParameter("FirstNameField");
        LastNameServlet = request.getParameter("LastNameField");
        EmailServlet = request.getParameter("EmailField");

        System.out.println(FirstNameServlet + "\n" + LastNameServlet + "\n" + EmailServlet);

        WelcomeName WelcomeNameObject = new WelcomeName();
        WelcomeNameObject.Fullname(FirstNameServlet, LastNameServlet, EmailServlet);

        request.setAttribute("FullName", WelcomeNameObject.FullName);
        request.setAttribute("EmailAddress", WelcomeNameObject.EmailAddress);

        request.getRequestDispatcher("Profile.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

Other Class Which is used to the actual calculation or Business Logic

```
package Model;

public class WelcomeName {

    public String FullName;
    public String EmailAddress;

    public void Fullname(String FirstName, String LastName, String Email) {
        FullName = (FirstName + " " + LastName);
        EmailAddress = (Email + "@gmail.com");
    }

}
```

Comment: You really need to read up on multi-threading and thread safety in general.  C.f. Brian Goetz's *Java Concurrency in Practice.*  A couple of simple lessons answering questions like this won't be enough.

Comment: If you don't have a more specific question; your input would better go to codereview.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 0):

I see no thread-safety issues in the code you presented.  Thread safety is primarily a function of how the code uses shared data, therefore I looked for

- instance variables of your servlet class, which are shared between threads if the servlet container uses the same servlet instance to service requests in multiple threads;
- objects shared via the servlet context or session objects; and
- static variables of any class that are accessed by your servlet or JSP.

Those are not the only forms that shared data can take, but they are the ones that could have been applicable to your web application, as you presented it.  You do not have any data sharing via any of those mechanisms, so your servlet and JSP, as presented, are thread-safe.

If you *did* access shared objects, that would not automatically make your code non-thread-safe, but you would need to protect your accesses with proper synchronization to ensure their thread safety.  As a functionality issue, you would then also want to take care with your synchronization, so as to avoid the possibility of blocking threads for any significant length of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Please clear me one thing, does class WelcomeName in package Model has something to do with Thread-Safety? As this class has instance Variables. The real job is done by WelcomeName class, I have a created an object WelcomeNameObject in doPost method of servlet class and used Servlet to Data in/out to html page, real job is done by WelcomeName.

Comment: @WaleedKhan, yes, class `WelcomeNameObject` has instance variables, but that does not matter for thread safety because no instance of that class is shared between threads (by any of the means I described in my answer).  When I said "instance variables of your servlet class", I meant exactly that -- in other words, instance variables of class `PersonalDataServlet`.

Comment: What if take
WelcomeName WelcomeNameObject = new WelcomeName();
out of the doPost method of servlet class, will it still be the thread-safe?

Comment: @WaleedKhan, Methods' local variables have no direct bearing on thread safety.  They are not a vehicle by which data can be shared between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Each method invocation has its own stack frame allocated for it, no other thread accesses it. All local variables are allocated on this stack frame. For the WelcomeNameObject, it's created on the heap, but the only references to it are on the stack frame of the method invocation creating it, and on the request object (even if the request object changed something on the welcomeNameObject, the method invocation is finished by then so there's no conflict). There is no opportunity for other threads to get a reference to it and change it, so it is thread-safe.

If you move the declaration of your welcomeName variable so that it's an instance variable in your servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/PersonalDataServlet")
public class PersonalDataServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private WelcomeName WelcomeNameObject;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
```

then the result will be unsafe. The servlet container keeps a pool of threads to execute requests on, it sends those requests to the same instance of your servlet, so concurrent requests can modify the contents of the servlet's instance variables. For instance one thread might enter the method, create a new instance of the object and assign it to the instance variable, then populate it, then another thread could invoke the method and create a new instance of the object and assign *that* to the same instance variable, so that the first invocation would return an object entirely different from the one it just created.

Answer (score -1):

You can use SingleThreadModel. Your servlet class implement this interface, after this your servlet is thread safe.

Comment: It provides threadsafety but at the cost of sacrificing concurrency. SingleThreadModel is deprecated as of servlet api 2.4, for good reason.